# How to make a macro that will transfer/distribute data from one cell to various cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I would like to ask is a macro could be address this automation.

I would like to transfer/distribute data from 1 cell to various cell.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't even require a macro, select the cells you want to split, then in data tab click "text to columns". There choose "delimited" and "next", for delimiter select "other" and type `-` then "finish" and you're done

Comment: +1 for text to columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't even require a macro:

- select the cells you want to split
- in data tab click "text to columns"
- There choose "delimited" and "next"
- for delimiter select "other" and type `-`
- "finish" and you're done

Answer (score 1):

**This simple UDF (Macro) will help you to split the Values into Columns.**

```
Function SplitValues(a As String, b As String)
Dim Text() As String
Text = Split(b, a)
SplitValues = Text
End Function
```

**How it works:**

1. Copy & Paste this VBA code as Module.
2. I'm assuming that you have data in `Column B` so write this formula in Cell `D2`.

   ```
   =SplitValues("-",B2)
   ```
3. Fill the Formula Right till it's 
   needed.
4. Press `F2` & finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, now Excel will convert it into an Array formula, finally fill the Formula Down.

   ```
   {=SplitValues("-",B2)}
   ```

**Note:** 
Delimiter "-" is editable, if required you may replace it with others also.